# Delphi freeing complex objects that have been created several levels agon

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks

I have a memory Management issue. Can you help me?

What I know:

1. any object that has been created has to be destroyed.
2. if the type of an object is an interface to that object, then whenever that variable cease to exist the object will be destroyed, and the memory is returned to the heap (if there is no reference count left)
3. (what I am not sure of) if an object contains (an/more) object(s), you should write a destructor always (?):

- that destructor should have the "inherited;" word written somewhere (I think at the end)
- that destructor should free any objectList, object ... etc  (which in turn may call that object's destructor, etc)

4. In the case of number 2:

- will the memory of the objects IN that object be freed?
- They might continue to exist - creating a memory leak

In order to avoid this during chained method calls (services.repository.method : `Result.create(object)`

---

Second part : I try to use interfaces ...

Memory issues with functions resulting in creations of T/interfacesOfT/:

```pascal
type
  TorderLine = class(TPersistent)
  private
    productId: integer;
    productName : string;
    amount : real;
    price : real;
  public
    create(productId: integer; productName: string; amount, price: real);
    function getId: integer;
    funciton getProductName: string;
    function getamount: real;
    function getprice: real;
  end; 
   
  TorderLines = class (TPersistent)
  private
    orderlines: TObjectList<OrderLine>;
  public
    create;
    create(list: TStringList);
    procedure addOrderLine(orderline: TOrderLine);
    function getOrderLines: TObjectList;
    function SearchOrderLines(productId: integer): TOrderLine;
    destructor; { must exist in order to free the TObjectList 
                  is only called when TOrder.Free is called }
  end;

  iOrder = interface 
    function getOrderId: integer;
    function getSupplierId;
    function getorderLines: TOrderLines;
    function toString: string;
  end;

  iOrderHeader = interface
    function getOrderId;
    function getSupplierId;
    function toString: string;
  end;

  TOrder = class(InterFacedObject, iOrder, iOrderHeader);
  private
    orderId: integer;
    supplierId: integer;
    orderLines: TOrderLines;
  public
    create(orderId, supplierId: integer; orderLines: TOrderLines);
    function getOrderId: integer;
    function getSupplierId: integer;
    function getorderLines: TOrderLines;
    function toString: string;
  end;

  iOrderRepository = interface
    function findOrder(orderId: integer): TOrder;
    function updateOrder(order: iOrder): integer;
    function findInterFaceOfOrder(orderId: integer): iOrder;
  end;

  TOrderRepository = class (InterFacedObject, iOrderRepository)
    function findOrder(orderId: integer): TOrder;   { Here the TOrder.Create WITH TorderLines.create is done }
    procedure updateOrder(order: iOrder): integer;
  end;
 
  Procedure blahblahblah;
  var
    iorder: iOrder;
  begin
    iorder := orderRepository.findOrder(someInteger);
    writeln(iorder.toString);
    { don't worry here : no free has to be done }
  end

  var
    order : Torder;
    iorder: iOrder;
    iorderHeader: iOrderHeader;
    orderRepository : iOrderRepository
  begin {main }
    orderRepository := TOrderRepository.create;
    order := orderRepository.findOrder(someInteger);
    iOrder := order; { case 2 } 
    iOrderHeader := order; { case 3 } 
    blahblahblah;
    order.free; { case 1 } 
    { the Torder.Free is called, which in term calls TorderList.free}
    { we don't care about iOrder & iOrderHeader }
   order := orderRepository.findInterFaceOfOrder(someInteger); { Gives an error } {Case 5}
    iorder := orderRepository.findInterFaceOfOrder(someInteger); { works fine  } {Case 4}
end.
```

```pascal
{ Above should be Correct code with no memory leak
  More Abstract }    
function F : T (Result : T.create)
function G : interfaceOfT (Restul:T.Create)
function H : otherInterfaceOfT (Result: T.Create)

{ case 1 } x := F -> should work ok <memory has to be freed manually>
{ case 2 } y := F -> should work ok <memory does not have to be freed : Is that so ?>
{ case 3 } z := F -> should work ok <memory does not have to be freed : Is that SO ?>
{ case 4 } y := G -> should work ok <memory should not have to be freed>
{ case 5 } z := G : does not work
```

Are the above assumptions correct?

Additionally : when in the `blahblahblah`, the `Order` object (`iOrder`) is freed, then also the `TOrderLines` are freed? Or, are they lost in cyberspace?

Comment: Edit your question to see the differences of the preview/outcome and your text (beware of linebreaks without an empty line inbetween). Do not post/link pictures which only show text, but instead copy that text as citation into your question. Take the [tour].

Comment: There is a terminology problem in your question. You should first clarify it in your head and reformulate your question. A variable can hold an instance of an object or an interface implemented by a given object (And also other things out of the scope of your question). As you more or less said, any instance of an object you create must be at some point destroyed. This is true for a variable holding the object instance (Those are pointers) but also for true for the objects instance created by some object instance. And yes, the usual place is the destructor.

Comment: I can't understand much of this, the code makes no sense, and there doesn't seem to be a single clear question. Why don't you just buy Dalija's book on this topic and read that?

Comment: I'm new to OOP, and I am spoiled by Java-garbage collection. Although I write excellent spaghetti-code and I'm able to create big piles of mud without any effort. I took a peek to Dalija's book. Its just a bridge (of 10) too far at the moment. I'll editg my question to be more precise

Comment: Probably you should read the Object Pascal Handbook from Marco Cantu for a basic (not the programming language ^^) understanding

Comment: If you can't access Dalija's book then you aren't ready to write the code you want to write.

Comment: "*if the type of an object is an interface to that object, then whenever that variable cease to exist the object will be destroyed*" - only for class types that implement reference counting. For instance, classes that derive from `TInterfacedObject`, but not from `TComponent`.

Comment: I am afraid that Delphi memory management is a lot more complicated than Java GC. Even if you use plain objects without interfaces there are different scenarios that require different handling. If you use interfaces then situation is even more complicated as not all classes that support interfaces behave the same.

Comment: If reading a book is a bridge too far, then you will have to search on Stack Overflow or elsewhere for each particular code scenario and see how it needs to be handled. For start each of your classes that constructs some objects within constructor needs to have destructor that will free those objects. Your question as-is is too broad as it asks too many questions about different scenarios. And it is hard to give you advices about your particular code because declarations are not enough to determine what is going on in your code.

Comment: You definitely need destructors for any of your classes that construct some objects in constructor and you need to release those in destructor. Also your handling of odred object that descends from `TInterFacedObject` is wrong. You can read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33567190/freeing-interfaced-object

Comment: that last link was exactly what I needed, thank you very much

Comment: @David Hefferman : maybe. But when I want to use a car to do a job, I don't want to know how to program power-curves and injection timings.  Hence I'm a spoiled though productive java-programmer and might ditch Delphi cause I have no business knowing how to programm injection timing... and ... apparently it's dying anyway. I wonder why.

Comment: A better analogy is that you need to learn to drive in order to be able to drive